# Save Pest Damaged Sapling

Tags: trees, grafting, sprouting

It seems a rodent or other pest ate the leaves of my tree sapling (2" tall). The top appears to have been bitten off.

A few days have passed and I still have not seen regrowth. Is there a way to stimulate regrowth (perhaps cut back below the bitten part) or otherwise save the sapling, such as grafting a tiny branch from another sapling?

Comment: 2 inch (50mm) sapling - start over - they don't have much in the way of reserves at that size...

Comment: Pictures please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up the sapling recovered. I improved the cage to prevent additional rodent damage. The sapling sent up a second shoot. It is shorter than others planted at the same time but appears to be healthy.